# Creating Delete User Unit Test Django rest_framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling to figure how to get the id of the user I created using the `create_user()` function in my unit test.

Unit test below:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework import status


DELETE_URL = reverse('user:delete_user')


class PrivateUserApiTests(TestCase):
  """Test the users API (private)"""

  def setUp(self):
    self.user = create_user(
      email='tes111t@test.com',
      password='test123',
      name='name'
    )
    self.client = APIClient()
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

  def test_user_successful_delete(self):
    """Test that user was succesfully deleted"""
    payload = {'email': 'test@test123.com', 'password': 'test123'}
    create_user(**payload)  # Here is where I create the user I want to delete
    user = get_user_model().objects.get()
    res = self.client.delete(DELETE_URL) # I'm not sure how to pass the id of the user I just created.
```

The way my url works is: (the id passed in is the user that is deleted)

`0.0.0.0:8000/api/user/delete-user/id`

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('create/', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='create'),
  path('token/', views.CreateTokenView.as_view(), name='token'),
  path('me/', views.ManageUserView.as_view(), name='me'),
  path('all_users/', views.RetrieveUsersView.as_view(), name='all_users'),
  path('delete-user/<int:pk>', views.DeleteUserAPI.as_view(), name='delete_user')
]
```

When using the `self.client.delete()` How do i pass in the id?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `reverse` like this:

```
response = self.client.delete(reverse('user', kwargs={'pk': user.pk}), follow=True)
```

Although that would require an API endpoint containing information about your **user** including their `pk`